# how to validate window registry script

Tags: php, file-upload, registry, validation

hey every one
I newbie in php and i make simple upload page
and I need to validate window registry file
first I try to validate .reg but I tried by creating a plain text file by inserting the extension. reg it validated. I want to open file after upload and validate character in file
and I do not know yet how to check of it

thank you for any suggest

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Validate how? "yep, that's a text file", "yep, that's a registry setting" or "yep, this registry file won't destroy my system or impregnate my dog"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good luck with this (What I am saying is that it will not be easy, fast, or recommended)...

Here's a PDF that greatly details the registry file format:

http://www.sentinelchicken.com/data/TheWindowsNTRegistryFileFormat.pdf